# PowerShell batch

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am reading data from CSV which is having 10000 items and creating on SharePoint list of items. I want to put that in batch using PnP PowerShell. Someone suggests to me batch functionality how to use it?

Comment: `batch functionality` to do what?

Comment: it will create item batch wise, like 1000 items for each batch it will loop and update in SharePoint list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm, your question is about performing actions in batches of max. 1000 items at a time while the input comes from a much larger CSV file.

For that, you can do like below:

```
# import the large (10000 items) csv file in a variable
$data = Import-Csv -Path '<your input Csv file>'

# now loop through that in batches of max. 1000 items
$counter = 0
while ($counter -lt $data.Count) {
    # determine the amount of rows to process
    $maxRows = [math]::Min(1000, $data.Count - $counter)
    # loop through the data array using indexing in batches of $maxRows size
    for ($index = 0; $index -lt $maxRows; $index++) {
        # perform your PnP* action here on each item
        # referenced by $data[$index + $counter]
    }
    # increment the main counter
    $counter += $maxRows
}
```

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to do the reference inside loop for example Add-pnolistitem -list $listname -values in this query. With example of title column

Comment: @Liz Inside the `for ($index....` loop, for convenience, just use a variable to store the current item from the csv and use its properties (by name of the csv headers) for your commands: `$currentItem = $data[$index + $counter]`. To get for instance the 'Title' property, simply use dot-notation: `$currentItem.Title`